# Element API - 'String' to 'kebab-case'

Tags: filter, plugin-elementapi

I want to convert a String into kebab-case.

```
'Hello there' -> 'hello-there'
```

I'm working in the Element API, so haven't got the pleasure of using the simple Twig filter. I guess there is a way of doing it in PHP. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually use the [StringHelper::toKebabCase](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/StringHelper#toKebabCase-detail)  function for this:

```php
$string = 'Hello there';
$result = StringHelper::toKebabCase($string);
// => 'hello-there'
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how to call this function please?

Comment: Trying this: $urlslug = toKebabCase($member->membersCompanyName); results in: Call to undefined function Craft\toKebabCase()

Comment: @AdamMenczykowski Just updated the answer with an example.

Comment: $string = StringHelper::toKebabCase('test this string'); does it!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could make use of some php functions to do this:

`$string = 'Hello there';`

First [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string using a space as the seperator

`$result = explode(" ", $string);`

This will give you an array like `array(0 => 'Hello' 1 => 'there')`

Then you can [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array, using an `-` as the "glue"

`$result = implode('-', $result);`

Which will then give you `Hello-there`

Then use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to make it lowercase

`$result = strtolower($result);`

To simplify this, you can just do it all at once

`$result = strtolower(implode('-',explode(" ", 'Hello there')));`